# remote debug python on aarch64 edge device

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, pycharm, remote-debugging

I wish to debug python code which is deployed remotely on an edge device. The device has aarch64 cpu architecture and does not have connectivity to internet (It serves as an access point itself).

I tried debugging using **vscode Remote-SSH** ,
but that doesn't work.I tried a few versions of the plugin: 0.49, 0.51 and also changed settings such as **Remote.SSH: Use Local Server** , but it always fail,
since host can't run wget/curl to download data.

I also tried using **pydevd** and **debugpy**, but it seems they do not support aarch64.

Any suggestions on how to use one of the above, or another tool to get the job done are most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,
I was able to clone [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy) and do the following changes:

- deleted:
  src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_amd64.so
  src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_x86.so
- modified:    src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/linux_and_mac/compile_linux.sh
  src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/linux_and_mac/compile_mac.sh  and commented out the lines for building amd64/x86

I was than able to build and deploy manually the python site package.
When running it on the device, there is a warning about amd64, but seems to be working.